# multirow doesn't seem to work

Tags: tables, columns, multirow

**EDIT: The problem now is that in the table, between 'Baseline' and 'Action' there is a space that I want to remove (look the image below). 'Action' is indented, and it's ok, but it's too detached from 'Baseline'. Any suggestion?**

I'm trying to use the `\multirow` command, but it doesn't work. The result is a 'scribble'. My table is a bit more complex than the following, but I reduced it for simplicity. Substantially, this is the method by which I use `\multirow` for the 'Description' column. Is it correct? Am I mistaking something?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[]{array}
\usepackage[]{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage[]{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.15\columnwidth}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.15\columnwidth} l 
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.15\columnwidth}}
\toprule
Study                  & Description        &  Conditions & Mean (SD) judgement error\\
\midrule
Haggard e Clark, 2003  & \multirow{3}
                       {0.15\columnwidth}{
                       $n=8$ (6 females).}  & \textit
                                            {Baseline}    &                          \\
                       &                    & \hspace{12pt}                                                                                                  
                                            Action        & -1 (43)                  \\
                       &                    & \hspace{12pt}
                                            Tone          & 41 (36)                  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `*` in the second argument of `\multirow` causes the natural width of the third argument to be used as the width for the multirow cell and this is (I guess) not desirable; perhaps what you meant is `\multirow{2}{0.15\columnwidth}{$n=8$ (6 females). Voluntary...}` instead?

Comment: Exact! That's the problem. Many many thanks.

Comment: Then I'll turn my comment into an answer so you can (if you consider so) accept it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Now I'm notycing another problem. In the table appears a space between 'Baseline' and 'Action'. I tried to remove `\hspace`, but nothing. This happens each time I define a new multirow column, and only for the first row of the subsequent column. Any cue?

Comment: Of course, but it is not clear to me what the final look of your table should be... Can you perhaps make a drawing of the expected result and add it to your question, so I can see how the entries should be?

Comment: Ok, I updated my question.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is is something like that what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `*` in the second argument of `\multirow` causes the natural width of the third argument to be used as the width for the "multirow" cell and, in this case, this is not desirable. Seeing the structure of your table, you seem to want something like

```
\multirow{2}{0.15\columnwidth}{$n=8$ (6 females). Voluntary...}
```

perhaps also changing the first argument to a more suitable value.

After seeing the edit to the original question, here's some modification to your code producing the desired result; notice that `\multirow` is used in the cells for the first and second columns to prevent the problem you mentioned:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.15\columnwidth}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.15\columnwidth} l 
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.15\columnwidth}}
\toprule
Study & Description & Conditions & Mean (SD) judgement error \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{0.15\columnwidth}{Haggard e Clark, 2003}  
  & \multirow{3}{0.15\columnwidth}{$n=8$ (6 females).}  
  & \textit{Baseline}  &  \\
& & \hspace{12pt}Action & -1 (43) \\
& & \hspace{12pt}Tone & 41 (36) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm wondering if it is more useful to use another table environment, for my purposes. My table is long, and using `\multirow` each time is not so comfortable.

Comment: @this.is.not.a.nick I've updated my answer with a simpler solution.

Comment: Very very well @Gonzalo, this solution is more elegant, of course. Thanks again.